# jQuery select element "on change" doesn't work second time

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I am not sure about what the bug is here. I am getting a JSON from server on each selection on `select box`. According to the JSON I am creating new form elements. On first selection, everything works fine, but second one doesn't trigger my event handler.

```
$('#planned_process').on('change', function(e){
  var $this = $(this);
  var parent = $(this).parents('.form-group').next();

  // if (e.added){
  $('.inserted-elm').remove();
  console.log('selected process :', $this.val());

  record = {
    ...,
    "tags":[
      "dummy-tag"
    ],
    "priority":1,
    "is_valid":true,
    "planned_start_time":"2014-01-01T21:01:00",
    "selected_recipies":[

    ],
    "planned_duration":"23",
    "created_date":"2014-08-19T06:45:15.669",
    "planned_input":[

    ],
    "last_editor":[
      "",
      ""
    ],
    "planned_output":[

    ],
    "created_by":[
      "",
      ""
    ],
    "planned_resources":[

    ]
  };
    _.each(record, function(val, key){
      var nameType = 'planned-process-disabled';
      var type = 'text';
      var elm = '<!-- start of element -->' +
          '<div class="form-group inserted-elm has-error"' +
          ' data-id="' + 'QQQ' + '">'+
          '<label for="process_' + key + '" class="col-sm-4 control-label">'+
          key + ' [' + nameType + '] '  + ' :</label>' +
          '<div class="col-sm-8">' +
          '<input name="parameter_values' + '" type="'+ type +'" id="' +
          key + '" ' + 'value="'+ val + '" ' +
          'class="form-control" disabled="disabled"/></div> </div>' +
          '<!-- end of element -->';
      parent.before(elm);
    });
});
```

Here is a jsbin example:

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/xewutucosipu/1/edit)

Comment: The page content toggles on successive change events. What's not working?

Comment: It's working for me: `selected process : dummy` `selected process : dummy-2`. Maybe I'm unclear on the problem.

Comment: select first value in selectbox, new form elements will be created. Then select second one. Oops. there should be form elements `again`. @isherwood

Comment: First one populates, second one clears, third populates, fourth clears.. etc.  So to say that it doesnt work the second time is misleading.

Comment: @showdev ah yes. but the same process should be running for both option. Form elements arent created if you select other option after select one.

Comment: @paqogomez Sorry, didn't understand your point :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have:

```
var parent = $(this).parents('.form-group').next();
//...
$('.inserted-elm').remove();
```

The `$('.inserted-elm')` also selects the element in `parent`, which means the code is appending to a removed element half the time. To fix it, swap the 2 statements:

```
$('.inserted-elm').remove();
//...
var parent = $(this).parents('.form-group').next();
```